# PHP Redirect To Page Based On Variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website with 2 types of membership, lets call them "basic" and "premium". What I want to happen is for site links to redirect the user to the relevant profile page based on their membership status, but I don't want there to be too much emphasis on what type of member they are in the url. I'll try to explain it better:

> username_1 = Basic Member
>
> username_2 = Premium Member

URL Redirection

> website.com/basic.php?user=username_1
>
> website.com/premium.php?user=username_2

Output

> website.com/username_1
>
> website.com/username_2

Any ideas how this can be achieved and if it can, how would the direct linking be effected, i.e. typing www.website.com/username_1 directly into the browser?

Comment: This is not really simple as it sounds. Look up PHP sessions.

Comment: Thanks @AmalMurali I will do. Anything in particular I should look at in sessions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have a working user system, and some kind of routing so that anything after the website.com/ is matched as a username. In the code that handles the user profile page, you have access to the username, and can get the user's profile from that.

Assuming you store the user's membership type in the profile, simply just check for that value and include the appropriate view. Might not be the best practice and how things are usually done, but here's a sample:

```
$user = get_user_from_db($username);
if ($user->member_type == 'basic') include 'profile/basic.php';
else if ($user->member_type == 'premium') include 'profile/premium.php';
```

It's not so much of the link redirection that matters. What matters is how you handle the user when loading his or her profile page.

Comment: Thanks, I'm all for doing things a little differently so I'm definitely going to look into doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

Your case could be resolved with php login system with admin features:

http://evolt.org/node/60384